# Javascript split to split string in 2 parts irrespective of number of spit characters present in string

Tags: javascript

I want to split a string in Javascript using split function into 2 parts.

For Example i have string:

```
str='123&345&678&910'
```

If i use the javascripts split, it split it into 4 parts.
But i need it to be in 2 parts only considering the first '&' which it encounters.

As we have in Perl split, if i use like:

```
($fir, $sec) = split(/&/,str,2)
```

it split's str into 2 parts, but javascript only gives me:

```
str.split(/&/, 2);
fir=123
sec=345
```

i want sec to be:

```
sec=345&678&910
```

How can i do it in Javascript.

Comment: @ajax333221. It's a good question! Mentioning other language syntax doesn't make it a bad question nor a translation question.

Comment: Use `indexOf` to get the index of the first `&`. Then use the `substring` function to extract both parts. But it's impossible to be blocked by this if you google "javascript string functions".

Comment: @gdoron didn't say it wasn't, I just feel he could attempt to do a little more himself. Remember, SO is one of the last options

Comment: @ajax333221. How do you know he didn't try enough? Crystal ball? and **who said SO is the last option?!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [split string only on first instance of specified character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character)

Comment: @ajax333221: i tried, then after i asked SO. I think SO as always the best option to get if i am not able to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of `split`:

```
str='123&345&678&910';
splited = str.match(/^([^&]*?)&(.*)$/);
splited.shift();
console.log(splited);
```

output:

```
["123", "345&678&910"]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var subStr = string.substring(string.indexOf('&') + 1);
```

View this similar question for other answers:

[split string only on first instance of specified character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character)

Answer (score 3):

You can remain on the `split` part by using the following trick:

```
var str='123&345&678&910',
    splitted = str.split( '&' ),
    // shift() removes the first item and returns it
    first = splitted.shift();

console.log( first ); // "123"
console.log( splitted.join( '&' ) ); // "345&678&910"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function:

```
function splitter(mystring, mysplitter) {
    var myreturn = [],
        myindexplusone = mystring.indexOf(mysplitter) + 1;

    if (myindexplusone) {
        myreturn[0] = mystring.split(mysplitter, 1)[0];
        myreturn[1] = mystring.substring(myindexplusone);
    }

    return myreturn;
}

var str = splitter("hello-world-this-is-a-test", "-");

console.log(str.join("<br>"));
//hello
//world-this-is-a-test​​​
```

The output will be either an empty array (not match) or an array with 2 elements (before the split and everything after)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yMkJk/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

I have that:

```
var str='123&345&678&910';
str.split('&',1).concat( str.split('&').slice(1).join('&') );
//["123", "345&678&910"]



str.split('&',2).concat( str.split('&').slice(2).join('&') );
//["123", "345", "678&910"];
```

for convenience:

```
String.prototype.mySplit = function( sep, chunks) {
   chunks = chunks|=0 &&chunks>0?chunks-1:0;
   return this.split( sep, chunks )
              .concat( 
                  chunks?this.split( sep ).slice( chunks ).join( sep ):[]
               );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the use of `split()` and `replace()`?:

Given we have that string `str='123&345&678&910'` We can do

```
    var first = str.split("&",1); //gets the first word
    var second = str.replace(first[0]+"&", ""); //removes the first word and the ampersand
```

> Please note that `split()` returns an array that is why getting the index with `first[0]` is **recommended**, however, without getting the index, it still worked as needed i.e `first+"&"`.

Feel free to replace the "&" with the string you need to split with.

Hope this helps :)