# String split returns an array with more elements than expected (empty elements)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I don't understand this behaviour:

```
var string = 'a,b,c,d,e:10.';
var array = string.split ('.');
```

I expect this:

```
console.log (array); // ['a,b,c,d,e:10']
console.log (array.length); // 1
```

but I get this:

```
console.log (array); // ['a,b,c,d,e:10', '']
console.log (array.length); // 2
```

Why two elements are returned instead of one? **How does `split` work?**

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: yeah i really hate it when one must omit ending separators. so annoying when trying to write consistent code or values or just editing a strict-type json

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the correct and expected behavior. Given that you've included the separator in the string, the split function (simplified) takes the part to the left of the separator ("a,b,c,d,e:10") as the first element and the part to the rest of the separator (an empty string) as the second element.

If you're really curious about how split() works, you can check out pages 148 and 149 of the ECMA spec (ECMA 262) at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Here is a direct link to the method specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.14.

Comment: "the split function takes the part to the **left** of the separator as the first element" – THIS answered the WHY this happens.

Answer (score 105):

You could add a filter to exclude the empty string.

```
var string = 'a,b,c,d,e:10.';
var array = string.split ('.').filter(function(el) {return el.length != 0});
```

Comment: Please note `filter()` is an ECMAScript 5 array function so additional code would need to be included to use this functionality if your browser doesn't support this. Please look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info and the code needed to implement this method.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it solves the problem - returns what is expected - instead of linking to some docs.

Answer (score 49):

A slightly easier version of [@xdazz version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836180/819355) for excluding empty strings (using [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
var array = string.split('.').filter(x => x);
```

Answer (score 19):

Use [**String.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with [**Array.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
var string = 'a,b,c,d,e:10.';
var array = string.split ('.').filter(item => item);

console.log(array); // [a,b,c,d,e:10]
console.log (array.length); // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

trim the trailing period first

```
'a,b,c,d,e:10.'.replace(/\.$/g,''); // gives "a,b,c,d,e:10"
```

then split the string

```
var array = 'a,b,c,d,e:10.'.replace(/\.$/g,'').split('.');
```

console.log (array.length); // 1

Comment: This simply returns a string "a,b,c,d,e:10", not an array, which is why the length is 1.

Comment: Hi @caseyjhol, the length of the string would be 12 not 1. the call to split always returns an array so the length is 1. It's my intention here to show that the call to split('.') returns an array of length 1. My answer is correct.

Comment: You're right - I misread the original question and thought he was trying to convert it to an array using the comma as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the string ends with the `.` character - the second item of the array is empty.

If the string won't contain `.` at all, you will have the desired one item array.

The `split()` method works like this as far as I can explain in simple words:

1. Look for the given string to split by in the given string. If not found, return one item array with the whole string.
2. If found, iterate over the given string taking the characters between each two occurrences of the string to split by.
3. In case the given string starts with the string to split by, the first item of the result array will be empty.
4. In case the given string ends with the string to split by, the last item of the result array will be empty.

It's explained more technically [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it's pretty much the same for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Using_split()):

> Note: When the string is empty, split() returns an array containing
>   one empty string, rather than an empty array. If the string and
>   separator are both empty strings, an empty array is returned.

```
const myString = '';
const splits = myString.split();

console.log(splits); 

// ↪ [""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, split does what it is made to do, it splits your string. Just that the second part of the split is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because your string is composed of 2 part :

1 : a,b,c,d,e:10

2 : empty

If you try without the dot at the end :

```
var string = 'a,b,c:10';
var array = string.split ('.');
```

output is :

```
["a,b,c:10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string with one "." in it and when you use string.split('.') you receive array containing first element with the string content before "." character and the second element with the content of the string after the "." - which is in this case empty string.

So, this behavior is normal. What did you want to achieve by using this string.split?

Answer (score -1):

try this

javascript gives two arrays by split function, then

```
var Val = "abc@gmail.com";
var mail = Val.split('@');

if(mail[0] && mail[1])  {   alert('valid'); }
else    {   alert('Enter valid email id');  valid=0;    }
```

if both array contains length greater than 0 then condition will true