# Count words comma separated javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have try make function to display number of remaining tags in input tag, but problem is because can't find solution to count as i need,

```js
$("#keywords").on("keyup change input paste", function(e) {
  var content = $("#keywords").val();
  var words = content.split(",");
  var num_words = words.length;
  var limit = 7;
  if (num_words > limit) {
    var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(",");
    $("#keywords").val(content.substring(0, lastIndex));
    return false;
  } else {
    $(".cr_keywords").text(limit + 1 - num_words + " tags remaining");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keywords" />
<div class="cr_keywords"></div>
```

[image]

Should be '0 tags remaining'

Comment: So add `$('.cr_keywords').text()` line to the if.....

Comment: But than i will have 7,6,5,4,3,2,0  tags remaining

Comment: `limit + 1= 8`...`num_words= 7`, `8-7 = 1` 1 tag remaing...where is the problem? o.O am I missing something? o.O wouldn't be the case to add `>=` in your if statement?

Comment: Remove your `+ 1`. You're adding one to the limit for no discernible reason, so your limit is 8, not 7.

Comment: Not for no reason, I thought he had an array and I was thinking 'arrays start at 0'. Sheesh I need to find some food, I'm getting stupid.

Comment: if i remove +1 i will have 6 tags remaining but you can enter 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a solution

```js
$("#keywords").on("keyup change input paste", function(e) {
      var content = $("#keywords").val();
      var words = content.split(",").filter(item => item);
      var num_words = words.length;
      var limit = 7;
      if (num_words > limit) {
        var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(",");
        $("#keywords").val(content.substring(0, lastIndex));
        return false;
      } else {
        $(".cr_keywords").text(limit - num_words + " tags remaining");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keywords" />
<div class="cr_keywords"></div>
```

Updated with var words = content.split(",").filter(item => item);

now it starts with 7 tags remaining and the result is as you expect i guess.

Comment: close, it says 6 tags remaining at start

Comment: Empty input "6 tags remaining" when you enter 1,2,3,4,5,6, you will have 0 tags remaining, should be 1... maybe is problem content.split(",") maybe need regex for this?

Comment: if you write a tag, is normally it say 6 remaining or not!!! What must say if you dont write nothing and what when you write the first tag??

Comment: content.split is returning 1 too many, try `var num_words = words.length-1;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836062/string-split-returns-an-array-with-two-elements-instead-of-one

Comment: Try enter one words and delete all from input tags you will have 6 tags remaining, when you start writing you will must have 7 tags remaining after first comma counting to 6 and etc... last comma will count 0

Comment: @dmikester1  but than you can enter up to 8 tags

Comment: you can still type commas

Comment: Yes that si still problem :(