# How to split a String based on first occurence?

Tags: java, regex

How can I split a String based on the *first* equals sign `"="`?

So

`test1=test1`

should be transformed into `test1, test1` (as an array)

`"test1=test1".split("=")` works fine in this example.

But what about the CSV string

```
test1=test1=
```

Comment: @netinept java language

Comment: What result do you want from "test1=test1="?

Comment: [Split string only on first instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462826/split-string-only-on-first-instance-java)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of `split` as seen in the [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

If you want the split to happen as many times as possible, use:

```
"test1=test1=test1=".split("=", 0);    // ["test1","test1","test1"]
```

If you want the split to happen just once, use:

```
"test1=test1=test1=".split("=", 2);    // ["test1","test1=test1="]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The `int` parameter is the *limit*. Try `"test1=test1=test1".split("=", 0);`

Comment: @mikeyaworski You apparently didn't read the documentation I linked to, which says: "If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible"

And *of course* you would change whatever the input string is to match the use case.

Comment: Yes, I apparently did. And as such, I'll answer with a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) because there is another [`.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method that takes in two parameters: the regex and the *limit* (limiting size of array). So you can apply the `int` limit to be only `2` - where the array can hold only two elements.

```
String s = "test1=test2=test3";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("=", 2))); // [test1, test2=test3]
```

Or

```
String s = "test1=test2=";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("=", 2))); // [test1, test2=]
```

Or

```
String s = "test1=test2";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("=", 2))); // [test1, test2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the first "=" in the string by using the method indexOf(), then use the index to split the string.

Or you can use

```
string.split("=", 2);
```

The number 2 here means the pattern will be used at most 2-1=1 time and thus generates an array with length 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better job for a `Matcher` than `String.split()`.  Try

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^=]*)=(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("x=y=z"); 
if (m.matches()) { 
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

If grabs all it can up to the first equal sign, then everything after that.

If you *insist* on split, `s.split("=(?!.*=)")`, but *please* don't.