# How to divide string by empty space in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

So, I have the following situation:

```
private BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String line= reader.readLine();
String first = ?
String second = ?
```

So, I know that user will enter something like this: love cats and dogs.
I want that the first word (in this case love) is always in String first and everything else in String second. How can I do it as simple as possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split string only on first instance - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462826/split-string-only-on-first-instance-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = "love cats and dogs";
// split into 2 parts
String[] parts = line.split(" ",2);

String first = parts[0];
String second = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
int splitIndex = line.indexOf(" ");
String first = line.substring(0, splitIndex);
String second = line.substring(splitIndex + 1);
```