# Split string with limit, where last string contains the remainder

Tags: javascript, string, split

e.g. if I run this javascript:

```
var str = 'hello_world_there';
var parts = str.split('_', 2);

var p1 = parts[0];
var p2 = parts[1];
```

at the end, p1 contains "hello", and p2 contains "world".

I'd like p1 to contain "hello", and p2 to contain "world_there". i.e. I want p2 to contain the rest of the string, regardless of how many underscores it has (similar to how c#'s String.Split(char[] separator, int count) behaves.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var str = 'hello_world_there';
var parts = str.split('_');

var p1 = parts[0];
var p2 = parts.slice(1).join('_');
```

This will do an ordinary split, but then merge everything past the first match.

Comment: If you split by regex like `str.split(/\s+/)` then change it to `str.split(/(\s+)/)` (e.g. add parenthesis around the whole regex) and then use `slice(2).join("")` instead of `slice(1).join('_')` in the solution above.

Answer (score 8):

This is slightly different from taking the rest as is, but this was useful in my case:

```js
const [a, ...b] = 'foo/bar/baz'.split('/');
// => a: 'foo', b: ['bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try with:

```
var parts = str.split('_', 2);
var p1 = parts.shift();
var p2 = parts.join('_');
```

or:

```
var index = str.indexOf('_');
var p1 = str.substr(0, index);
var p2 = str.substr(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Write your own function:

```
function split(string, delimiter, n) {
    var parts = string.split(delimiter);
    return parts.slice(0, n - 1).concat([parts.slice(n - 1).join(delimiter)]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your *specific* case where you just want two parts, the simplest thing is `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
const index = text.indexOf("_");
const p0 = index === -1 ? text : text.substring(0, index);
const p1 = index === -1 ? "" : text.substring(index + 1);
```

Live Example:

```js
const text = "hello_world_there";
const index = text.indexOf("_");
const p0 = index === -1 ? text : text.substring(0, index);
const p1 = index === -1 ? "" : text.substring(index + 1);
console.log(`p0 = "${p0}", p1 = "${p1}"`);
```

I've found I want that often enough I have it in a utility module:

```
const twoParts = (str, delim = " ") => {
    const index = str.indexOf("_");
    if (index === -1) {
        return [str, ""];
    }
    return [
        str.substring(0, index),
        str.substring(index + delim.length),
    ];
};
```

But if you wanted to do more than just teh two parts, an approach that doesn't require rejoining the string after the fact would be to use a regular expression with capture groups:

```
const result = text.match(/^([^_]+)_+([^_]+)_+(.*)$/);
const [_, p0 = "", p1 = "", p2 = ""] = result ?? [];
```

Live Example:

```js
const text = "hello_world_xyz_there";
const result = text.match(/^([^_]+)_+([^_]+)_+(.*)$/);
const [_, p0 = "", p1 = "", p2 = ""] = result ?? [];
console.log(`p0 = "${p0}", p1 = "${p1}", p2 = "${p2}"`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp solution (you can change "|" to other chars e.g. "__" but not to "_")

```
var [p1,p2] = str.replace(/_/,"|").split("|");
```

```js
let str = 'hello_world_there'
let [p1,p2] = str.replace(/_/,"|").split("|");

console.log("p1:",p1);
console.log("p2:",p2);
```

Comment: I love your attitude but it just creates a new problem related to some random other character like `|`