# Splitting string on first equals sign in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Javascript to split some data out of a url The url looks  along the lines of....

```
var1=green&var2=yellow&newUrl=[url.php?id=2]
```

I am managing to split the url by the '&' signs to give me one array of three items. I am then trying to split this array by the first '=' sign to give me a list of fields and variables. Its working fine until it hits the second = sign within the newUrl field. Any ideas of how I can split this string at the first '=' sign.

my code so far is...

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");

var vars = href.split("&");
for(i=0; i < vars.length; ++i){
    var str = vars[i].split("=");    
    alert(str[0] +':' +str[1]);    
    }    
}
```

my results are

```
var1:green   var2:yellow   var3:[url.php?id
```

Any ideas?

**Edit to show my final code based on Wand Maker's solution **

```
var vars = href.split("&");
for(i=0; i < vars.length; ++i){

    index = vars[i].indexOf("=")
    var str = [ vars[i].substring(0, index), vars[i].substring(index)]

alert(str[0] +':' +str[1].substring(1);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split string only on first instance of specified character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character)

Comment: I looked at that post, but couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below for splitting around `=`

```
index = vars[i].indexOf("=")
var str = [ vars[i].substring(0, index), vars[i].substring(index)]
```

Comment: Cool, with a little tweak to remove the = sign from the beginning of the second string that worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use join() for the third element in the array as below:

```
var lst = href.split("&");
var var1 = href[0].split("=")[1];
var var2 = href[1].split("=")[1];
var var3 = href[2].split("=").slice(1,2).join("");
```

Comment: is `str[1:]` a python slice? A Javascript slice is `str.slice(start,end)`

Comment: Yh just noticed and corrected it. Also I believe you either mean str.substr(start, end) or array.slice(start, end)

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitFirstInstance(str,item){
    var res = [];
    var found = true;
    res.push("");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length;i++){
        if (str[i] === item && found === true){
            res.push("");
            found = false;
        } else {
            res[res.length-1] += str[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
splitstr("I Want to Split First a","a"); // ["I W","nt to Split First a"]
```