# Split string on first comma into array

Tags: javascript

I'm having a string like below that i would like to split only on the first `,`. so that if i for instance had following string `Football, tennis, basketball` it would look like following array

```
["football", "tennis, basketball"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var array = "football, tennis, basketball".split(/, ?(.+)?/);
array = [array[0], array[1]];
console.log(array);
```

Inspiration: [split string only on first instance of specified character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character)

---

**EDIT**

I've actually found a way to reduce the above function to one line:

```
console.log("football, tennis, basketball".split(/, ?(.+)?/).filter(Boolean));
```

`.filter(Boolean)` is used to trim off the last element of the array (which is just an empty string).

Comment: Note that this actually results in the `array` being `["football", "tennis, basketball", ""]`

Comment: @SnoringFrog No it doesn't. Overwrite the `array` variable with what I put in the `console.log`. That's the correct answer. You are not outputting the same value as the above function.

Comment: @SnoringFrog There, now I overwrite my array variable instead of outputting the result? Does that cause less confusion?

Comment: That creates the `array` value OP was expecting/asking for, yes