# splitting of strings in javascript which involves backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we split the following tag to extract the substring **"PDSGJ:IO.HJ"**.

`var input = "\\initvalues\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some"` .

I tried the following:

```
var input = "\\initvalues\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some";
var b = input.split('\\');
alert(b[1]);
```

Note: The format remains the same , **\\,\, ~** format is same and mandatory for all strings .

But the problem is , I get the output as: **initvaluesPDSGJ:IO.HJ~some**.
I need **'\'** also because I need to further split and get the value.

Any other method is there to get the value?

Comment: this might be worth a read :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character#4607799

Comment: I think `\\initvalues\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some`  is getting changed to `\initvaluesPDSGJ:IO.HJ~some` as you are not escaping the `\\`. Try after escaping it, it should work.

Comment: to have your code working, you should escape your "\" when you set your test string: `input = "\\\\initvalues\\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some"`. When the string comes with this value it is ok, but when entering it literally, you have to escape them

Comment: Like as pointed out you need to escape the '\' to '\\',.. also after doing this your going to get  `["", "", "initvalues", "PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some"]`, so you will also want `alert(b[3])` for your `PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some `

Comment: `var input = "\\initvalues\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some";` now when you do :- `console.log(input);` it will show you `\initvaluesPDSGJ:IO.HJ~some`

Comment: Yosvel's answer has been accepted because , it doesnt target on changing the input format . Input remains as it is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
var input = '\\initvalues\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some',
    b = input.match(/[A-Z]+:[A-Z]+.[A-Z]+~[a-z]+/);
  
console.log(b && b[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is interpreted as an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). So you're gonna have to add another backslash for each backslash.
Then directly search for the last backslash and then slice the string:

```
var input = "\\\\initvalues\\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some";
var index = input.lastIndexOf('\\');
var str = input.slice(index+1)
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed correct, like the others already mentioned, that a backslash is interpreted as an escape character.

To output proper result, thus as a list.

```
var txt='\\\\initvalues\\PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some';
txt.split(/\\\\/).pop(0).split(/\\/)

(2) ["initvalues", "PDSGJ:IO.HJ~some"]
```