# What RegEx would I use to parse sections of text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to write a program that converts lists of terms and definitions to flashcards. My though was to use RegEx to parse the input in the following way:

```
term(1)-def(1)
term(2)-def(2)
term(3)-def(3)
term(4)-def(4)
term(5)-def(5)
```

which parses to:

```
terms = ["term(1)","term(2)","term(3)","term(4)","term(5)"];
definitions = ["def(1)","def(2)","def(3)","def(4)","def(5)"];
```

I'm very new to RegEx syntax, so I'm not sure how exactly I would do this.

Further context:

- Each line contains this format: `term`-`definition`\n
- I will be writing this in JavaScript so I can host the program on a website (yes, I am aware I don't need to use JS. It's just the simplest to get set up).
- The RegEx should only avoid the first `-`, as one might appear in the definition. `-` will never appear in the term.

Comment: will `-` ever occur in the term?

Comment: No @erik258, though it should probably be able to handle the case where there is a `-` in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the input using one of the methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607745/split-string-only-on-first-instance-of-specified-character) and then push the results to `terms` and `definitions` arrays or perhaps a definition object:

```js
const inp = `term 1 - definition 1
term 2 - definition 2 - contains a hyphen
term 3 - def 3
term 4 - has - lots - of - hyphens`

const terms = []
const definitions = []
const defobj = {}

inp.split('\n').forEach(line => {
  [term, definition, _] = line.split(/\s*-\s*(.*)/)
  terms.push(term)
  definitions.push(definition)
  defobj[term] = definition
})

console.log(terms)
console.log(definitions)
console.log(defobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture everything up to the first `-` as the term and everything that follows as the definition:

```js
const item = "term(1)-def(1)";

const rx = /([^-]+)-(.*)/;

const [, term, def] = rx.exec(item);

console.log(`term is "${term}"; def is "${def}"`);
```

But why not use JSON/objects for the input and save yourself all that pain? No string parsing necessary.

```js
const cards = [{
    term: "term 1",
    definition: "definition 1",
  },
  {
    term: "term 2",
    definition: "definition 2",
  },
  {
    term: "term 3",
    definition: "definition 3",
  }
];

const root = document.getElementById('root');

function makeElement(content, className, tag = 'div') {
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  el.innerHTML = content;
  el.className = className;
  return el;
}

function appendCard(info, parent = root) {
  const card = makeElement('', 'card');
  const term = makeElement(info.term, 'term');
  const def = makeElement(info.definition, 'definition');
  card.appendChild(term);
  card.appendChild(def);
  parent.appendChild(card);
}

cards.forEach(item => appendCard(item));
```

```css
:root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  background: aliceblue;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.definition {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: skyblue;
}

.card:hover .definition {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>mouse over to reveal definition</p>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I forgot to properly specify, the idea is someone could drop in their list, and it would be converted automatically to save the trouble of converting to array by hand.

Comment: Answer updated with a regex solution.