# How to split a string using a separator if the previous char is not an escape character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to parse some data which represents a URL and a description.

The format is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, Ask` (`url, description`).

Because the comma is allowed in URLSs, the backend escapes the comma with another comma (but only in the URL part).

The following input string, for example, should be parsed as:

- Input: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,, some weird path parts, Ask, with comma`
- Output:

  - URL: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, some weird path parts`
  - Description: `Ask, with comma`

I'm struggling to find how to split the string on the first unescaped occurrence of `,` .

My test case is `a,,b,, c, d, e,, f, ,, g`. I should extract exactly two substrings: `a,b, c` and `d, e,, f, ,, g` (the description part does not have to escape commas).

I tried using a regular expression:

```
const input = 'a,, b,, c, d, e,, f';

const re = /(?<!,), /;

const parts = input.split(re);

console.log(parts, parts.length);
```

Another attempt is to use a non-regex solution:

```js
const findUnescaped = (input: string): number => {
    let start = 0;

    while (true) {
        const i = input.indexOf(', ', start);

        if (i === -1) { // No separator at all
            return -1;
        }
        if (i === 0) { // Separator at begin of string
            return 0;
        }
        if (input[i - 1] !== ',') { // Found the separator without a preceding comma
            return i;
        }

        start = i + 2; // Looks further

    };
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4J11N)

However, this function does not handle `,,,`  (one escaped comma and the separator) properly. It considers the previous comma as an escape character, even if it is not.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `String.split()` always splits on *all* occurrences of a match by default, it is built-in. [Pass `2` as the second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209925/3832970).

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. My main issue is related to proper handling of escaped comma.

Comment: Ok, then you'd better remove that part about getting 3 parts.

Comment: Well, if you escape a comma with another comma I guess you can use `.split(/(?<=(?<!,)(?:,,)*), /, 2)`

Comment: Mainly it sounds like the regex term OP is looking for is "negative lookbehind". It's not necessarily the number of parts, but the quality of escaped vs. unescaped commas. If someone added a fourth field down the line (which this read), code that just grabs the first three (as opposed to requiring 3) will continue to work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your expression seems to work as expected, including the escaped commas. If you want to post an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split a string into two parts before a non-"escaped" comma you can use a `String.match()` pattern like

```js
const parts = input.match(/^([^,]*(?:,,[^,]*)*),\s*(.*)/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkEcHE/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]*(?:,,[^,]*)*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than a comma and then zero or more occurrences of a `,,` followed with zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,\s*` - a comma and zero or more whitespace chars
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string.

If you are limited to a `String.split`, *and* your regex will be run in an ECMAScript 2018+ JavaScript environment, you can use a splitting approach with

```js
const parts = input.split(/(?<=(?<!,)(?:,,)*), (.*)/)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkEcHE/3).

*Details*:

- `(?<=(?<!,)(?:,,)*)` - a positive lookbehind that makes sure there is

  - `(?<!,)` - a location that is not immediately preceded with a comma
  - `(?:,,)*` - then having zero or more occurrences of even amount of commas
- `,`  - a comma and space.
- `(.*)` - Group 1: captures the rest of the string.

Demo:

```js
const inputs = ['a,, b,, c, d, e,, f', 'a,, b,, c,,, d, e,, f'];
for (let input of inputs) {
  console.log(`== Testing: ${input}`)
  const [_, url, description] = input.match(/^([^,]*(?:,,[^,]*)*),\s*(.*)/)
  console.log(`URL: '${url}', Description: '${description}'.`)         // Solution 1
  console.log(input.split(/(?<=(?<!,)(?:,,)*), (.*)/).filter(Boolean)) // Solution 2
}
```